# When should the preposition *cum* be added as a suffix?

Tags: preposition, suffixes

I was reading Plautus and came across *quacum*, which set in motion a few observations:

1. Most beginning Latinists are familiar with the following constructions with **first- and second- person and reflexive pronouns**, which usage seems to mandate **in all cases**.

   > - *cum* + *te* = *tecum*
   > - *cum* + *nobis* = *nobiscum*, etc.
   > - *idem* for *se*, *vobis*, and *me*
2. Other constructions (according to my cursory research) appear to be **optional**. I have seen this especially with **relative pronouns**:

   > - *cum + qua = quacum **or** cum qua*
   > - *cum + quibus = quibuscum **or** cum quibus*
3. **Everything else** seems simply **forbidden**:

   > - *cum + Marco =/= Marcocum*
   > - *cum + filio =/= filiocum*
   > - *cum + eo =/= eocum*

I have a few related questions:

1. Are there good counterexamples where *cum* + personal pronoun is not combined, e.g. *cum te*?
2. Are there examples of *cum* being added at the end of a word not in the first or second category?
3. Is there any difference between *cum qua* and *quacum*?

Let me know if this seems too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Lewis/Short, s.v. cum:

Cum in anastrophe. So always with the pers. pron.: mecum, tecum, secum, nobiscum, etc.; cf. Cic. Or. 45, 154; Prisc. pp. 949 and 988 P.; and in gen. with the rel. pron.: “quocum (quīcum), quacum, quibuscum, quīcum (for quocum),” Cic. Or. 45, 154; Liv. 38, 9, 2; Cic. Att. 5, 1, 4; Cic. Verr. 2, 2, 31, §§ 76 and 77; Caes. B. G. 1, 8; Cic. Rep. 1, 10, 15; id. Att. 4, 9, 2; id. Off. 1, 35, 126; Quint. 8, 6, 65; 10, 5, 7; 11, 2, 38. But where cum is emphatic, or a demonstrative pron. is understood, cum is placed before the rel.; cf.: “his de rebus velim cum Pompeio, cum Camillo, cum quibus vobis videbitur, consideretis,” Cic. Fam. 14, 14, 3: “adhibuit sibi quindecim principes cum quibus causas cognovit,” id. Off. 2, 23, 82; Liv. 1, 45, 2.—

Comment: Could you format this so it's more readable?

Answer (score 1):

The enclitic use of *cum* is actually much broader than just these cases, but this is obscured by modern choices about the use of spaces. A phrase like *magna cum laude* probably had enclitic *cum*. The Romans, who didn't use spaces, wrote it as MAGNACVMLAVDE; if they'd used spaces, it's possible they would have written *magnacum laude*, just like *tecum*.

Comment: I think this is more than just a matter of spaces: *magna cum laude* is natural word order whereas *tecum* reverses it. It would be more like saying *laude cum*...

Comment: @brianpck I don't see how one is more natural than the other -- "logical" word order would be *cum magna laude* and *cum te*. In both cases *cum* becomes enclitic instead of proclitic.

Comment: sorry--I was unclear. My point was the presence of spaces isn't material: I could just as easily ey asking why the Romans write *te cum* or *qua cum*. The point is not that they are combined into one word, but that the preposition *follows* the (pro-)noun it modifies.

Comment: @brianpck OK, thanks for clarifying. I think they're still underlyingly the same thing, though -- postposing of *cum* isn't really a syntactic phenomenon (preposition follows the head of the noun phrase it governs) but a phonological one (preposition becomes enclitic and follows the first word in the phrase it governs). At least, that's how linguists think of it these days; it's a common phenomenon in Indo-European generally.

Comment: **Spaces** In Oxford CCC ms122 (Corpus Gospels) Irish Eleventh Century, some proclitics are written as one word with their nouns. So you have *amatheo,* (from Matthew) on the Alia Ev. pages. You expect that with verb prefixes, as *consurgere,* but there are several with nouns.

Comment: @Hugh I believe the same is true of Roman inscriptions that use interpuncts. I wonder if there are any cases of the *magna cum laude* construction in those.